# Android Gradle plugin error: string too large to encode using UTF-8 written instead as 'STRING_TOO_LARGE'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Unable solve this issue after updating gradle plugin. I tried all the solutions given to stackoverflow but none is working for me. project build.gradle is in below:

```
    buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should downgrade your version to gradle 3.1.3 for a particular time being. If you want the you can clear the "build cache" to fix it. Or else you can try using the "stripe" dependency, check this out over here https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android and if you are trying to enable minification in your projects gradle file the you should add this too -> "-keep class com.stripe.android.** { *; }".

Try anything of the above mentioned. Thank you.